# instancedMesh: the vertex will lose precision

Tags: three.js

Using THREE.InstantMesh, when the size of the geometry box is 2, and the position is placed at a distance of about 8000000 from the origin, the vertex will lose precision.
[lose precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxhoP.png)    [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFtF1.png)

Comment: This is just a limitation of floating point precision. You will either need to scale your "universe" down into a safe range like 0.01 to 10,000, or develop a scheme to page in sections of the universe and keep them centered around the origin.
Here's an article that touches on some of the details.

https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1965/visualizing_floats.php?print=1

Comment: Does this only happen with `THREE.InstancedMesh`? Meaning you see no issue when using just `THREE.Mesh`?

Comment: f32 can safely store *integers* in the range -16,777,216 to 16,777,216

which is half of your 8,000000 number.. so at that range, your numeric precisions is probably jittering around .5. If the size of your object is around 1, or smaller, then you will see exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: You'll also lose some precision during the trip through the vertex transformation pipeline, which may be compounded by the instancing logic.. which is what Mugen may be alluding to.

Comment: When using THREE.Mesh, the same distance from the origin, if you set a large value in the vertex, moving the camera will produce jitter, but with ".position", setting the offset will not. With THREE.InstancedMesh, no matter how, accuracy will be lost.

Comment: Is the instancedMesh object converted to camera space during rendering?           var project_vertex = "vec4 mvPosition = vec4( transformed, 1.0 );\n#ifdef USE_INSTANCING\n\tmvPosition = instanceMatrix * mvPosition;\n#endif\nmvPosition = modelViewMatrix * mvPosition……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All game engines run into this floating-point precision issue when values get too high. Here's an example of [a rocket that flew too far away from the origin](https://twitter.com/Crefossus/status/704615579697590272), and the geometry started falling apart after a few minutes.

You have two solutions:

1. You can scale down your world and assets, or
2. Instead of moving your camera around the world, move the world and keep the camera still. That way everything that's visible in the camera's viewport is closer to 0, where floating-point precision is high.